# Load precompiled Handlebars template in Node script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

I have a simple Handlebars template at `email-template.hbs` that I'd like to precompile and load into my `app.js` file without reading from the filesystem and compiling it every time `app.js` is run.

Right now, I have something that looks like this:

```
var handlebars = require('handlebars');
var fs = require('fs');

var source = fs.readFileSync('./email-template.hbs', 'utf-8');
var template = handlebars.compile(source);
```

I'd rather have something like this:

```
var handlebars = require('handlebars');
var template = require('email-template');
```

Where `email-template.js` is the precompiled `email-template.hbs` template.

Comment: http://handlebarsjs.com/precompilation.html

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'm new to Node and Handlebars, and had the same question.

The trick is to precompile your template using the `-c` flag (which precompiles to Node's CommonJS module format, and gives it the path to the handlebars runtime module it needs).

Given you've already followed the directions for [setting up precompilation](http://handlebarsjs.com/precompilation.html) (`npm install handlebars -g`), then for your example of generating `email-template.js` from `./email-template.hbs`, try running this on the command line:

```
handlebars ./email-template.hbs -f ./email-template.js -c handlebars/runtime
```

...which should produce an `email-template.js` with

```
var Handlebars = require("handlebars/runtime");  var template = Handlebars.template, templates = Handlebars.templates = Handlebars.templates || {};
```

at the top. Then you can use it in your `app.js` like so:

```
var Handlebars = require('handlebars/runtime');
var hbtemplate = require('./email-template.js');

// You don't even seem to need the "var hbtemplate =" above, 
// as precompiling puts your template into the Handlebars object.
var template = Handlebars.templates['email-template'];
// ...then you can use template(data) to generate the HTML string
```

Comment: Thanks for this, i was missing the handlebars/runtime after the -c option, I didn't find it clear that this was required.

Comment: @Jason this doesnt seem to work any more. I get an error saying that `Cannot read property 'email-template' of undefined`. More about this at https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/955

Comment: @Jason my mistake. I was importing `handlebars` instead of `handlebars/runtime`. But this time it didnt give me an error but `template` was `undefined`. So I was going thru the js file and made slight change to the above code. I replaced the your code snippet with `var template = Handlebars.templates['email-template.hbs'];`

Comment: All day, I've been at this all day. Finally just left work, went home, had a drink, watched a movie and then took another look at this and saw this answer. THANK YOU SO MUCH

Answer (score -1):

Just make yourself a helper function:

```
// requireHbs.js
var handlebars = require('handlebars');
var fs = require('fs');
var memoize = require('lodash.memoize');
module.exports = memoize(function requireHbs(templateName){
  var filename = './' + templateName + '.hbs';
  var source = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf-8');
  return handlebars.compile(source);
});
```

Then use it like this:

```
// app.js
var requireHbs = require('./requireHbs');
var template = requireHbs('email-template');
```

Comment: The goal is to avoid reading the template from the filesystem completely.